# Any issues using an IBM DataPower ESB w/ WCF development?

Tags: wcf, soa, esb, ibm-datapower

I'm looking to implement an ESB and wanted to get thoughts related to "how" my web services might change (WCF) or -- how my client apps that consume these services might "need to be revised" (-- other than a new service ref to the ESB path --)

The device I'm working with specifically is the "WebSphere DataPower XML Security Gateway XS40"

Answer (score 1):

I assume you picked the XS40(yellow one) for the security aspects of the gateway.  That is enforcing WS-Security, WS-Policy, etc.  While the datapower box can be configured to support these, your messages will have to include the WS-Security header information.

This information typically goes in the Secuity block of the soap Header and can hold a signature, rsa key, user name tokens, or x509 certificates.

More information about WS-Security can be found in the [1.0 spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0.pdf).  (Keep in mind that different ESB 'products' may provide support for different versions of the specification.)

Now, if your just looking to use the Datapower box for content based routing (or proxying of web service messages) you'll need to make sure your messages have enough information imbedded for the datapower box to route that message to the correct service.

So, assuming that your WCF communication is configured to use soap messages (not the binary .net remoting) datapower shouldn't have any trouble deciphering what's in your messages(xpath) and routing appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that i am going to use basichttpbinding for my wcf service,this is because i am goign to MTOM encoding to transfer a document. MTOM encoded transfers can be done onyl with basichttpbinding. So will i have a problem with IDB data power in this scenario since DP enforces WS-* ?